# Why UITableView cell separatorInset is default to 15, when view controller's root view Layout Margins is 16?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, margins

On iPhone 6s, when I set cell separator line left inset to 14, is show 15, I think that is because it set `preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = true` by default.

But from apple doc: "The side margins vary depending on how and where the controller is presented, but can be either 16 or 20 points(depending on the device). You cannot change these margins."

When I add a view to the side of root view by auto layout, and set `preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = true`, the distance from the edge of root view to the view I added is 16 on iPhone 6s, so it is not aligned to the left edge of the table view. How can UITableViewCell use `preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = true`, and the side margins is 15, not 16?

Answer (score 1):

After some logs, I know why, that is because:

```
tableView.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
```

And the table View's layoutMargins is (8, 15, 8, 15) on iPhone 6; (8, 20, 8, 20) on iPhone 6 Plus.

On apple documents, it is only said: "The default margins are 8 points on each side. You can modify these margins based on your app’s needs."

But the table view's layoutMargins is (8,8,8,8) on `viewDidLoad()`, then change to (8, 15, 8, 15) later on iPhone 6.

This is very confusing when I want to add a view left align to the table view, and the subview's left edge left align to table view separator line. I had to update the view like this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    totalBar.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = tView.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins
    totalBar.layoutMargins = tView.layoutMargins
}
```

So that I don't need to hardcode the margin values for 6 and 6 Plus, and for even Apple change the value in future.

Comment: Absolutely amazing.