# Is there any way to change the iOS Large Title left margin?

Tags: ios, large-title, preferslargetitles

I would like to know if is there any way to change the iOS Large Title left margin property. I tried to find the answer for it on the web, but I did not succeed.

---

*Extra question: is the default margin between items and the horizontal sides of the screen 15? The reason I am asking this is because I am trying to align the large title with the rest of the elements of my app, that has 15 left/right margin to the screen.*

Thank you :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.firstLineHeadIndent = 10 // This is added to the default margin
UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : style]
```

Assuming that the 'rest of the elements' in your 'extra question' are tableview items, then yes, 15 seems to be a default margin: [Why UITableView cell separatorInset is default to 15, when view controller's root view Layout Margins is 16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982576/why-uitableview-cell-separatorinset-is-default-to-15-when-view-controllers-roo)

Comment: This work on iOS 12, but on iOS 11 it cuts the tail of the title of.

Any solution for iOS 11?